# How to uppercase a String in FitNesse automation

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm using FitNesse tool to automate some task and I need to insert a String in uppercase.
I'm not sure if there is a fixture by default in Fitnesse to do this or how to import a java lib into FitNesse wiki script , any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To add a directory, or `.jar` to the classpath accessible to the wiki use [`!path`](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.ClassPath). Your wiki can then access the classes, so you could call a method to convert a string to uppercase from a table (the method would be considered a 'fixture method' then).

An introduction on how wiki pages and Java code interact can be found in the user guide: http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.FixtureCode

I would recommend using the [Slim test system](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM) for new tests, but if you have existing tests they might use [Fit](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.FitFramework). Test fixtures for each test system run in their own process so they cannot share state.